# Is it possible to get date/time stamp in EST and not CST, without doing a DATEADD?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I have cloud pages sign up forms that have a hidden field for a date/time stamp upon submission.  We are simply using **Now()** and it works great - except the data is in CST, and not EST.

I did some research and a suggestion was to use the Default Date/Time in a DE to set the value, but that too is in CST (I checked under Admin, our account is listed as EST).

We can do a DateAdd but then we'd have to change this every 6 months (too risky, not slick).

```
value="%%=DateAdd(Now(),"2","h")=%%"
```

Has anyone had luck finding a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the [**SystemDateToLocalDate()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/datetime_ampscript_functions/systemdatetolocaldate/) AMPScript function:

Local Time For User: `%%=SystemDateToLocalDate(Now())=%%`

Comment: Thought about that, but if a user is on the West Coast we still need the data to be in EST, as we want all of our data to be consistent.

Comment: Well, if you want it consistent (and would like to stay sane), then I'd suggest sticking with CST.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs All Date/Time values are stored in Salesforce in GMT format - what do you mean by consistency?

Comment: UTC time in Marketing Cloud? Where?

Comment: I think we might just do the transformation within our offline DB when the data is imported.  Thank you for the input @AdamSpriggs